# How do I keep a div (a site-wide pullup) with a particular ID hidden after user has closed it once

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a banner at the bottom of my website that fades in after 7 seconds, and it has a little close button for the user to fade it out.

What I want to achieve is for the user to only have to press close once per visit. While they are clicking around the blog (from one post to another) I don't want to keep bothering them with the notice.

What I have is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

const showPullup = localStorage.getItem('showPullup');

if(showPullup === 'false'){
  $('#pullup').hide();
}

$(function() {
  $("#pullup").delay(7000).fadeIn(400);
});

    $('#pullup .close').bind('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(200);
        localStorage.setItem('showPullup', 'false');
    });

</script>
```

As you can see, I don't know what I'm doing, so if anyone could help me hide this thing while users browse our site I would be very very grateful.

Comment: Move you code inside `$(function() {

});
`

Comment: based on the local storage value either display or hide the pullup 


$(function() {
if(showPullup === 'false'){
  $('#pullup').hide();
}else{
  $("#pullup").delay(7000).fadeIn(400);}
});

Comment: now its not showing at all?

Comment: Oh, its not showing because i closed it. Yay : ) thank you : ) so much : )

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following css

```
#pullup
{
  display: none;
}
```

And use this javascript

```
$(function() {
    const showPullup = localStorage.getItem('showPullup'); // Get the item from local storage

    if(showPullup !== 'false'){ // If it doesn't equal false, i.e. its not been opened before show the showPullup
        $("#pullup").css('display', 'block'); // Set display: block
    }
    // On click close, set local storage to false
    $('#pullup .close').bind('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(200);
            localStorage.setItem('showPullup', 'false');
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry to be so useless, but can i still have the delay bit if i use this?